# Best performance on embedded DB

Tags: c#, database, embedded-database

I'm looking for an embedded DB solution (e.g., SQLite, Access, etc). Out of the ones that are out there (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database), which one would have the best performance? Most of the DB access is queries. Inserts and updates are rare.

Thanks.